# What is this phrase, "I hope we catch up," called when "catch" may be confused with what's done with a  baseball?

Tags: idioms, confusables

I asked someone “I hope we catch up soon” and he imagined himself being lightly or violently tossed in the air hoping someone will catch him.  Obviously a non-native English speaker.

Is there a term for this phrase or type of misunderstanding?  Are there other examples of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called an [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom).  An idiom is a phrase that has a figurative meaning that differs from the literal definitions of the individual words.

Here is a list of [english idioms.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aEnglish_idioms) Several variations of "catch up" are on the list.

Comment: "Conflicts?" Always conflicts? Necessarily conflicts? Citation, please :-)

Comment: "Conflicts" was a poor word choice. I've rephrased my answer.

Comment: An idiom is a phrase THAT has a meaning ... Pedantically yours,

Comment: I think a little pedantry is to be expected on an "English Language & Usage" site.

Answer (score 1):

There could possibly be an occlusion of "...to [object in question]..." in the phrase "catch up..."  In that case, it would make sense to use "up to", as it would be demonstrative of a spatial orientation between two objects (namely, the speaker in question in relation to the person whom he/she/they is/are trying to catch [up to]).  Therefore, using "catch" is practically the same when applied to people or spherical objects, but adding "up [to]" adds the notion of two objects approaching one another.

Comment: I totally misread the actual question at hand.  Please refer to dbyrne's post.

Comment: I upvoted  you because your answer was a tongue-in-cheek complete hoot! So please delete your comment!

Answer (score 1):

**Catch up** is a phrasal verb and so the two words should not be separated in this context.

Therefore, we are not dealing with the word *catch* as in *catch the ball*,

but rather *catch up* as in *If you run fast enough, you might catch up to the others.*

Here, **catch up** means to close a gap between yourself and someone who is ahead of you.

When we use it in this sense, we are *catching up* to the time that has passed; Since last I saw you, many things could have happened to me so my 'life story', in a way, has moved on from what you know. When you meet me and I tell you what has been going on, I *catch you up*, meaning 'bring you up-to-date'.

The important thing then to realise is that **catch** and **catch up** are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man :-) How to translate the idiom that has no translation?

"I hope that, in the fullness of time, our Red Sox boys may regain an equality *vis-à-vis* their Yankee opponents with respect to score." Or

"we will, one fervently hopes, find ourselves co-located with our friends whose breathtaking pace has outstripped us and left us here; and soon."

How would you translate "catch me up"? "I'm going ahead to catch the Red Sox - Yankees game at the barroom down the street? Catch me up!"